# How to convert Date to timestamp string in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm new to JSP/JSTL, there're lots of answer convert String to java Date, I need to convert a Java Date variable to a timestamp string and send it by url parameter, how to do it with JSTL ?

I have my date object in JSTL,

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${a.mydate }" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd- HH:mm:ss"/>
```

I need a timestamp string of ${a.mydate}, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fmt:formatDate to parse any date to print as needed, but as you are getting a string input, it has to be parsed to Date and then you can use the formatter to display the date or time.

Assuming **${a.mydate}** is the string query meter, use the below code. It should follow the same pattern as shown, if you have a different pattern, update it accordingly.

```
<fmt:parseDate value = "${a.mydate}" var = "parsedMyDate" pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy" />
<c:out value = "${parsedMyDate}" />
```

> Prints: **Wed Oct 20 00:00:00 GST 2010**

Below patterns are used to display in different formats.

```
<fmt:formatDate type = "time" value = "${parsedMyDate}" />
```

> Prints**14:27:18**

```
<fmt:formatDate type = "both" value = "${a.mydate}" />
```

> Prints **23-Sep-2010**

```
<fmt:formatDate type = "both" dateStyle = "short" timeStyle = "short" value = "${a.mydate}" />
```

> Prints **23-Sep-2010 14:27:18**

You can see more examples in this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm

> As a whole it can be as below:

```
<c:set var = "myDate" value="03-07-2019 02:10:24"/>
<c:out value="${myDate}"/>

<fmt:parseDate value = "${myDate}" var = "parsedMyDate" pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" />
<fmt:formatDate type = "time" value = "${parsedMyDate}" />
Time is: ${parsedMyDate.time}
```

> Time is: **1562145024000**

Comment: but `type="time"` is not the timestamp string

Comment: So, you would like to display a timestamp using the jstl tags and not date and time. Are you referring to something like this in java?
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));   

Could you please provide more information on what is the requirement?

Comment: If you are passing this as a variable from some servlet or java class, you can always convert it into timestamp in the back end and just return the value which you would like to display on the page. (This will avoid logic on your JSP)

Comment: Updated my solution to print the time as well in the JSTL. Hope that is what you are looking for